# Signup for email accounts from GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, email, gmail-api

I am faced with a rather strange request and there isn't much material online tackling that.
I am building a web app on GAE ... front end, back end, datastore, blob store, user accounts, the whole nine yards ...

Part of the requirements is to have a user communication system, (users sending messages to each other, just like Facebook) as user emails are not to be shared among other users, and the web app shall only send emails to the user sign up email strictly for security and administration purposes, and wont flood their inbox with notifications like some websites do.

I have narrowed narrowed it down to 4 options

Option 1:

Reinvent the wheel  - Build this whole system form scratch on the Datastore and Blob store. However, not only is it expensive, but also I am not gonna go through all of that (just saying honestly)

Option 2:

Build a bouncing system ... User A sends message to app ... app bounces email to User B. Not very Elegant, impossible to create threads and conversations, eats up app Mail Quota used for Marketing and what not.

Option 3:

Host My own Email server onsite. Patch an API servlet and run the whole show through API. Very valid, except that the client doesn't want anything on site, and I wont be around to maintain it for him.

Option 4:(Best option if someone helps out)

Implement option 3 on a 3rd party email provider. Which brings us to the question, is there any respectable email provider that allows account sign up through API ?? I need to create a shadow email account on a 3rd party server(that the user will never know it exists) every time someone makes an account on my app. Then store all emails and their generated passwords in the Datastore, and when user logs in my web app, web app logs in 3rd party server, retrieves messages and serves it. When he wants to send a message, web app gets the message, sends an email using API as well. If someone knows how to do that on Gmail, I would be eternally grateful (but I highly doubt google allows that)

Note

I can implement the whole setup on xmpp/Jabber servers as well but these free servers keep changing all the time and they change their configurations ... bottom line they are not very reliable.

Thanks a lot guys !! I really appreciate any feed back and if you have any other suggestions please don't hesitate !! This is by no means a solid plan yet.

Comment: I have also figured that I can create manually like 5 emails for sending and 5 emails for receiving on Gmail, index them through their subjects(User A to User B: blah blah blah), then search for all emails with subject containing "to User B" when User B requests inbox for example, but I dont think that would scale up at all ... correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I’m not following how options 2, 3, or 4 meet the requirements of the spec. If what’s asked for is an in-app messaging system that is explicitly not email-based, why are you bringing email into your proposed solutions?

Comment: not USER PERSONAL EMAIL based, but who cares where the data source is coming from or how its being handled ... they probably wont even understand if I try to explain. Bottom line is, users are not receiving tons of emails from my app every time someone interacts with them. As for how its done, well only you know now. Also You do have a point, option 2 is not valid as it will use the Users Email (It was very late at night)

Comment: Options 3 and 4 would merely create email accounts that the web app and only the web app will ever use. One email for each User. When user A send a msg to User B, the web app will send an email from the email created for user A to the email created for user B. When both of them log in my app, the web app will fetch the inbox contents of the emails created for them. Thats it, while never touching their personal email they used for sign up

Comment: It sounds like you believe using email as a back-end for a a simple user-to-user messaging system will save you some effort. I don't think that's even slightly true. I think you'll pay a tremendous cost in logistics (like the sign-up issue you pose), performance, and flexibility by shackling yourself to a system (email) that's designed to a lot of things (rfc2822, cc/bcc, pop/imap, boxes, folders, etc. etc) that you don't need. Option 1, for the problem you've described, is probably 30-50 lines of code in GAE.

Comment: Well thanks for the point of view !! I will definitely take it into consideration, but given that the datastore is not an RDB, dont you think its gonna take more that 30-50 lines of code, unless ofcourse we are talking about duplicating the message (inbox, outbox) , then do you think its gonna be rationally feasible ?? please let me know